# How to install a shower surround on an existing old bathtub?

Tags: bathroom, shower, bathtub

I recently bought a mid 1970s house and have been doing some renovations. Not a lot of experience with bathroom renos. There is a bathtub/shower combo. Standard size 60" x 30" alcove. The current shower surround left about a 3/4"+ gap between the top edge of the bathtub and bottom edge of the surround which was filled with a giant bead of caulking. I removed the caulking as I was going to get the bathtub refinished, but saw signs of rot in the 3/4" gap. I removed sections of the surround and the plywood behind the old surround was rotted 3" up from the bathtub edge. The studs behind feel solid and with no rot. The curious thing was this bathtub does not have a normal 90 degree 1" tall tile flange like I have seen before. It is more like a rounded rib running along the outside edge of the bathtub. I was originally looking to just get it refinished and replace the surround. This is an older cast iron tub that is framed in and rock solid. Is there a way to install a shower surround with this strange lip/ edge?

[image: Edge of bathtub]

Comment: how much space behind the lip to the wall

Comment: one year home warranty could cover the damages

Comment: @Ruskes   Think 1970s is more than a year old.

Comment: @the OP just bought the home, the usual is to have 1 year warranty on it regardless of the home age. aka home owner warranty, and seller pays for it

Comment: The top of the lip was roughly flush with the wall but was hidden by a ridiculous amount of caulking, and definitely no warranty on the home. I bought it as a fixer upper.

Comment: Could you get a closer image of what that tub lip looks like, please? Just [edit] it into your question. Also, if there was plywood behind the tub surround, now is a good time to replace it with something like cement board and a good water seal layer, just in case your new surface material should leak like the old one did.